# pure-ftpd doesn't apply umask to file permission

Tags: permissions, ftp, pure-ftpd

I'm trying to set up pure-ftpd on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with a default file permission for uploaded files, but it doesn't seem to apply my umask config for some reason.

I want the permission to be 660 for both files and directories.

In `/etc/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.conf` I changed the following line:

```
Umask  137:137
```

However, when new files are created they have permission 644.

My entire conf file can be seen [here](https://justpaste.it/7pqin).

Let me know if any additional information would help.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for mentioning it